# Ellipsize causes textview to shrink

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a `LinearLayout` which I populate with **TextViews** with `android:ellipsize="end"` but when ellipsize triggers, it causes my textview to shirk.

Here is the image:

[image]

Now if the textview does not triggers the ellipsize then it will display it correctly.

Here I remove all the textview that was triggered with ellip:

[image]

and my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_data_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_route_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/otd_stop_fragment_recycler_regular"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_added_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/otd_stop_fragment_recycler_added"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I make sure that when the ellipsize is triggered it wont shrink it.

Comment: Now this is very weird indeed :). Can you try without the padding? If that doesn't work either, as a workaround, would setting the height to a fixed dp be an option you would consider?

Comment: @kha setting a fixed height is a no go for me. :))

Comment: @DerGolem the xml above is just a child of the linear layout.

Comment: @DerGolem the two textview above is a switching views as you can see in the images it changes from one textview to another when clicked so having weight is redundant.